# Twitter bootsrap 2 row full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a `row` in Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.0 that goes full width with no right/left borders/margins, I've tried:

(**The style will than be a class in the css file**)

```
<div class="row" style="background:#5498CC; height:150px; margin: -40px 0px 0px 0px;">
    <div class="span12">

    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried this (taken from a question in StackOverflow):

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;  width: 100%;">
    <div class="row" style="background:#5498CC; height:150px;">
        <div class="span12">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second works better but still not right as shows here:

[image]

Still has borders on left and right. The point is that this div I'm creating **is already inside another `container` div**

Any help to fix this?

Comment: is the amazon para in bootstrap `row` class or the blue bg div??

Comment: @NoobEditor The blue bg div

Comment: based on 2nd code snippet of yours, doesn't seem to have any margin...see here...http://jsfiddle.net/8XKUR/   may b ur parent `div` has a problem, can you show its css??

Answer (score 0):

You should try moving the div outside a `.container`

Comment: I know, but can't. The project is at the end and is all setup thru PHP to write files in a certain order and position, for now I'd like to try some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me here (with Chromium) http://bootply.com/102654

I used `'row-fluid'` class instead of `'row'`.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 blue">
       content  -  content  -  content 
    </div>
</div>
```